# tab menu's using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

Am trying to create tab menus without using jquery tab plugins. and i created `tabheader` class as tab menu.while clicking its child `<a>` the class `tabed_contents` showed i try to achive using the `id` of `tabed_contents`in tab menu's anchor tag's href like this markup.

```
<ul class="tabheader">

<li class="active" ><a href="#fragment-1"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>

</ul>

<div id="fragment-1" class="tabed_contents">
aasd

</div>
```

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vivekranth/69z5B/2/)
I got the href value and make the resepected id to show form hide.Am completely Struck ed after that..help me out

my jq

```
 $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function() {

  var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `hide` all divs first like,

```
$('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function() {
    $('.tabed_contents').hide();// hide previously shown containers
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(href).show();// shows the div for which your tab is selected

    $('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li').removeClass('active');
    // add class to li
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: if i need to add a class to 'li' while this event means how should i do it..?

Comment: @VikranthVivek check my updated answer once I've added `class active in li`

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can see is that the elements stay shown, simply use the following line to hide all items before showing the respective one :

```
  $('.tabed_contents').hide();
```

Also is there a reason why you would not use [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Can you please elaborate on your question if you need more help on this, as you haven't actually specified what you want to achieve.

Comment: to make my site faster am reducing some plugins..so am not planing to use jqplugins

Comment: Understandable, but you probably won't gain much from not using jQuery UI and also you can customize what goes into your jQuery UI plugin using the following link : http://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using an anchor tag, you need to prevent the anchor's link from refreshing your browser. For this we can use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault). This involves passing in the event through the function call:

```js
...'click', function(event) { ...
```

Then calling:

```js
event.preventDefault();
```

On a side note, you shouldn't use jQuery's `attr()` method to pull the `href` of a link, instead you can simply use `this.href`.

All together, your function will end up looking like this:

```js
$('.tabs > ul.tabheader > li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    /* Prevent the link event from refreshing the page. */
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = this.href;
    $(href).show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any possiblites to add or remove classes to the parent of 'a' (mean to'li')